# can I disable for one query ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

In MYSQL DB setting is set as ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY

`@sql_mode ='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'`

I can disable this as a general using

`set @sql_mode = select replace ( @@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','')`

But is there any query condition by which this can be enabled for one query only?.

Comment: Store original SQL Mode value in a variable. Restore it after your query.

Comment: is there really no solution in fixing the query? Sounds like you are very close.

Comment: @Akina yes, thanks this could work but I am trying if any way to do this without changing any DB setting.

Comment: @danblack as this was previous existing query and showed error in new environment I didn't want to change query completely. But I think fixing query can help avoid future issues as well, thanks.

Comment: *I am trying if any way to do this without changing any DB setting.* SQL Mode is NOT "DB setting".

Comment: PS. Do not change SQL Mode. Edit your query, make it correct.